# Creating custom runtime image dedicated for specific modular application

Tags: java, java-9, jlink, java-module, jdeps

Let's say I'm developing a modular application that consists of 2 modules: `com.spacey.explorer` that depends on `com.spacey.rocket` module. I have their modular JAR files in some `bin` directory.

And I want to prepare lightweight JRE to run it. So obviously, I use the **jlink** tool:

```
$ jlink --module-path /opt/jdk-9/jmods:../bin --add-modules com.spacey.explorer --output ~/custom-jre3
```

Now when I list modules in my JRE I get the following:

```
$ java --list-modules 
com.spacey.explorer
com.spacey.rocket
java.base@9
```

That is, my application modules are bundled into JRE. But if I wanted to build a JRE that has just JDK-originated modules that are sufficient to run my application **and** keep my application modules separate, I **have to know** what my JDK dependencies are (in the example this is just `java.base`) and specify them explicitly like:

```
$ jlink --module-path /opt/jdk-9/jmods --add-modules java.base --output ~/custom-jre3
```

Is there any way to make **jlink** do this for me ? Or any tool that would figure out those JDK-originated dependencies for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html#BACCCJEH) tool. The option that could help is:

```
jdeps --list-deps <path>
```

> Lists the dependences and use of JDK internal APIs.

where `<path>` can be a pathname to a .class file, a directory, a JAR file.

**Note**: Use `jdeps -help` to list out all the option and their syntax. You can use

---

For example, I gave a try to a jar file in my machines .m2 folder, which would be treated as an *unnamed module* like:

```
jdeps --list-deps /.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.jar
```

***Output::***

```
java.base
java.desktop
unnamed module: /.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.jar
```

---

You can also make use of the

```
jdeps --jdk-internals --class-path <path> <path>
```

> Finds class-level dependences on JDK internal APIs.  By default, it analyzes all classes on --class-path and input files unless -include option is specified.

---

### *Update November 1,2017*

There is [future revision](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189202) change to make use of the same with `jlink` as :

```
jlink --module-path jmods --add-modules $(jdeps --print-module-deps myapp.jar) --output image
```

Answer (score 6):

To create a runtime image with `jlink` you need to specify the root modules with `--add-modules` - starting with these modules, jlink will build a module graph and include all resolved modules in the new image. You have used `--add-modules com.spacey.explorer`, so `jlink` includes *com.spacey.explorer* and all its dependencies.

To instead only include the JDK modules *com.spacey.explorer* depends on, you first need to determine those, for example [with jdeps](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/) (see also [nullpointer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331914/2525313)). Once you know those modules, you can define them as root modules with `--add-modules`.

In your example:

```
$ jlink 
    --module-path /opt/jdk-9/jmods
    --add-modules java.base
    --output ~/custom-jre-for-explorer
```

If there were more modules than just *java.base*, say *java.sql*, the command would look as follows:

```
$ jlink 
    --module-path /opt/jdk-9/jmods
    --add-modules java.base,java.sql
    --output ~/custom-jre-for-explorer
```